# Picking 3 balls from 10 balls, each one with a number from 0 to 9

Tags: combinatorics

Given that we pick 3 balls from 10 balls, each one with a number from 0 to 9, I need to define the following event: "Number of balls that we picked, whose number on them is odd, is even".
Meaning for example that (1,3,4) is in the subset that we want to find, but (1,3,5) is not.
I tried to calculate the cardinality of the subset and got $3 \choose 2$$*5*4*5 = 300$. I don't know if it's right. I should add that it's an ordered sample without repetitions. Did I do a mistake ? Thank you for your help

Comment: Break into cases.  Either we picked no odd balls and three even, or we picked two odd balls and one even.  In the first case, that would be $\binom{5}{0}\binom{5}{3}$  In the second case that would be $\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{1}$ for a total of $10+50=60$.  That is if order didn't matter.  If you care about order, then further increase by a factor of $3!$ for a new total of $360$

Comment: Don't forget that zero is also an even number, so you need to include all samples that contain no odd-numbered balls

Comment: My logic was that we either picked an odd ball on the first pick, so we got 5 possibilities, then we picked another odd ball so we're left with 4 possibilities, then we picked an even ball so we have 5 possibilites, and I multiplied it by 3 because we either can pick an odd ball first then an even then an odd, or an even then two odds, or two odds and then an even. Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: Again, because you could have picked three evens and it still counts as having picked an even number (*zero*) of odd labeled balls.

Comment: Oh ok sorry, I understand now. Thank you for your help ! You can post your answer if you want so I can accept it

Comment: Number of favorable ways is 360 out 720 ways without replacement. // 60 ways for no odd, 300 ways for two. So probability of even nr. of odd choices is 1/2. // Was going to ask whether with or without replacement, but then it's 500/1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment continued with simulation:

```
set.seed(2021)
odd = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(0:9, 3) %in% c(1,3,5,7,9)))
mean(odd==0 | odd==2)
[1] 0.49988  @ aprx 1/2
```

Approximate probabilities for 0, 1, 2, or 3 odd numbered balls.

```
table(odd)/10^6
odd
       0        1        2        3 
0.083837 0.417324 0.416043 0.082796
```

Multiplying by 720 possible outcomes suggests
60, 300, 300, 60 favorable outcomes for 0, 1, 2, 3
odd marbles, respectively. [That's 100 each for
EOO, OEO, OOE.]

```
720*table(odd)/10^6
odd
        0         1         2         3 
 60.36264 300.47328 299.55096  59.61312
```